# Is command javap not case-sensitive?

Tags: java

I created a very simple class Test.java

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] stringArr = new String[10];
        Object[] objs = stringArr;

        objs[0] = 1;

        System.out.println(objs[0]);
    }
}
```

so I can compile it by using `javac Test`, after that, I want to see the detail inside the Test class by using `javap` commond, but actually I made a mistake as below:

```
D:\>javap -private TEst
Compiled from "Test.java"  
public class Test extends java.lang.Object{    
public Test();
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}
```

as you see, I typed `TEst` after the javap command, but actually the command show the information of the class, after that I tired to use `javap -private TEST`, it is also working.

is it means `javap` is not case-sensitive?

Note:
My JDK version is:

> java version "1.6.0_43"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_43-b01)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.14-b01, mixed mode)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"is it means javap is not case-sensitive?". This is not about javap.. its about the cmd prompt where you are using these commands.. The cmd prompt is case insensitive... you can do cd.. or CD.. or cD.. They all do the same thing..

Comment: but if I try to use `java TEst` to run the exact class, I got an error:"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: TEst (wrong name: Test)"

Comment: do you have a test class... (I assume you are using windows.. ).. if test class exists in the location you are currently in, then case should not matter.. give the exact name of the class and try.. you will probably get the same error.. because the class is not present... have you compiled it??.. is it in your present directory? (or are you using the correct absoulte path?)

Comment: in my folder only have Test.java and Test.class two files. And I tested in Linux(ubuntu) just now, in linux, an error is shown "ERROR:Could not find TEst", maybe this is because the windows, but why `java` command and `javap` command have the different behavior?

Comment: java is not throwing error because your "TEst" file is not found.. its throwing an error because your "TEst" class is not found in your file (it looks for  the class name same as the file name)..  It looks inside your"TEst" and throws java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError because there is no class named "TEst".. your "environment/cmd prompt" is still case insensitive (in windows) but your java command execution doesnt say "ignore case and get class with classname same as filename".. got it?

Comment: I got it, basically `javap` is show the detail of the **class file**, but windows is case-insensitive, no matter the exact filename is, TEST.class, TeSt.class. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The Windows file system is "case friendly"; it will try an insensitive search. The class name in the file is. Notice that javap `Compiled from "Test.java"`

Answer (score 0):

I had got a similar error message when I tried to compile a program making slight case changes in the filename. I
It turns out that @TheLostMind is correct.., thank you sir